# TypeError: $.whenCallSequentially is not a function

Tags: jquery, selector

I want to know what's the meaning of `$.` and whether `whenCallSequentially` is a function of jQuery or not

Answer (score 0):

`whenCallSequentially` is *not* part of jquery, the only reference I can find is in this [web-scraper-chrome-extension](https://github.com/martinsbalodis/web-scraper-chrome-extension/blob/6b6c1885542eee89e97f65e6ba62207e90ac9f9b/extension/assets/jquery.whencallsequentially.js)

`$` is simply an [alias for jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> In the first formulation listed above, jQuery() — which can also be
>   written as $() — searches through the DOM for any elements that match
>   the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that references
>   these elements: